# How to check reports of sonarqube analysis in Embedded database? and how can we export this data

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops

I wonder, how sonarqube will generate analysis reports in Embedded database and what are the steps to see analysis reports in embedded database. Can we export that database from one to other database like MySQL?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the reports, you just need to browse the SonarQube web instance. Embedded database should not be used in production and there is no simple way to export H2 database to MySQL.

Comment: If I use MySQL or Postgres how can I export data. Thanks

Comment: You can export the database, but I'm not sure of which data you want to export.
If you want some kind of reports, you may want to have a look at Governance plugin : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+Plugin#GovernancePlugin-PDFReporting